# Passing sequence of letters to CNN - Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have data of the following format:

1. A sequence of 150 letters
2. The letters can only be A,B, C, D, E.
3. I have a total of 20k sequences
4. 10k of the sequences are labeled 1 and the other 10k are labeled 0

I converted the these 150 letters into one-hot vectors by doing the following:

```
from skimage.transform import resize
import numpy as np
def transform(data): #transform sequence into one hot encoding
    def one_hot_encode(seq):
        mapping = dict(zip("ABCDE", range(5)))    
        seq2 = [mapping[i] for i in seq]
        return np.eye(5)[seq2]

    train = np.zeros((len(data), 150, 5, 1), dtype=np.uint8)
    for idx, d in enumerate(data):
        seq = one_hot_encode(d)
        seq = resize(seq, (150, 5, 1), mode='constant', preserve_range=True)
        train[idx] = seq.astype('float32')
    return train
```

Now, I want to just pass this data into a simple CNN built from Keras. I'm building the model as:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(64,kernel_size=(3,3),activation='relu',input_shape=(150,5,1)))
model.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size=3, activation='relu'))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
model.summary()
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Now, I'm trying to train by doing: `history = model.fit(X_train, Y_train, epochs=100, verbose=False, validation_split=0.25, batch_size=10)`

But this keeps throwing the following error:

> InternalError: failed initializing StreamExecutor for CUDA device
>   ordinal 0: Internal: failed call to cuDevicePrimaryCtxRetain:
>   CUDA_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY: out of memory; total memory reported:
>   11721506816

I've trained images of size dimensions 512x512x3 which has far more input dimensions than this. So why is this causing this error?

Comment: I'd like to award a bounty on this question, but I can't for 2 days...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently your video card does not have enough memory to handle the input data, hence the error. Try reduce the batch size to 4 or 2, and run the same model again.

Comment: You're completely right actually, I hadn't cleaned my GPU memory... smh. thanks!